# PHP Class for SOAP Web Services?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm looking for a PHP class that will make it painless to work with a SOAP service. Ideally something that works like this:

```
$class = new SoapClass();
$class->addArgument('foo', '123');
$class->addArgument('bar', '123');
$class->url('http://example.com/services/xyz');

$result = $class->sendRequest();

$data = $result->data;
echo "$data->count results found.";
```

Any suggestions? I do have PHP 5.

Comment: Um... like SoapClient? (http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)  Granted, I don't consider that class exactly "painless."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a word, Nusoap.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/

```
$client = new soapclient('http://somewhere/path/to?wsdl', true);
$result = $client->call('method', [request array structure goes here] );
// -- Process $result
```

And a handful of examples ...

- http://wiki.reminderconnection.com/index.php?title=PHP_-_using_NuSoap
- http://www.richardkmiller.com/files/msnsearch_nusoap.html

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the native php soap client ?

http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Zend is another good alternative ( but you need to have the zend library then )

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.client.html

My last recommendation is WSO2

http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/php/

But soap is not painless so don't expect that. Use a REST architecture.